# Check if cell formatted as text contains a number

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I check if the cell value is numeric or not, for cells formatted as text?

I have a column which normally, but not always, contains numbers.  However, the column is formatted as text so that leading zeroes are retained.  I've discovered the `ISNUMBER()` function will always return `FALSE` for cells formatted as text, even if the value is numeric.  Is there any other way I can identify whether a value is numeric for a cell formatted as text?

I want to treat values with leading zeroes, like `012345`, as numeric.

Comment: You could try using double unary before the cell reference and then use the `ISNUMBER()` function so for a number it will return true while for those which are text will return false. That said --> `=ISNUMBER(--A1)` or could use `VALUE()` function as well. `=ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1))`

Comment: Both of those work, thank you.  If you'd like to make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above and since it has worked for user, posting it as an answer.

Using `Double Unary` or `VALUE()` function one can test whether the cell reference consists a true number or not.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B9</kbd>

---

```
=ISNUMBER(VALUE(A9))
```

---

Or

```
=ISNUMBER(--A9)
```

---

Using `Double Unary` or `VALUE()` it converts the text into numeric value, if the cells are true numbers then it converts else it returns an error. So after wrapping within `ISNUMBER()` returns `TRUE` for a numeric while `FALSE` for an error when the text formatted is not a number.

---